# R Package Development - point to objects called by function

Tags: r, package

So I've got a function that loads an RData workspace and uses the data in a dataframe therein to perform some computation. At the moment I am putting everything into a package and my question is where I should put that workspace/the dataframe in the package and how I should modify my function to point to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sec. 1.1.6 of the [Writing R extensions manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages) describes exactly what you are looking for.

> *The `data` subdirectory is for data files, either to be made available via lazy-loading or for loading using data(). [...]*
>
> *Data files can have one of three types as indicated by their extension: plain R code (.R or .r), tables (.tab, .txt, or .csv, see ?data for the file formats, and note that .csv is not the standard19 CSV format), or save() images (.RData or .rda). [...]*